# Is there a way to connect a Postgres 9 database client to a Postgres 8 system?

Tags: postgresql-9.5, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-fdw

I a now work mainly with Postgres 9.5, but I alsoo need to connect to a number Postgres 8 databases connect them probably as different schemas, if that is possible.
Are foreign database wrappers the kind of thing which makes this possible, or is there some built in support in Postbres 9.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via PostgreSQL FDW you can connect to any other PostgreSQL (as well as other databases), regardless of the version of the location (remote, local, or same) or version (older, same, or newer) of that other PostgreSQL.